# How to show the sum of all Prices that a Student has

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

- `Student` has_many `Lessons`
- `Lesson` belongs_to `Prices`

How can I show the `sum` of all `Prices` that `Student` has in `show` action of the `StudentsController`?

Comment: Lesson belongs_to :price, what all you have tried so far

Comment: Looks like you would want to add a has_many :prices, :through => :lessons relationship on Student.  Then student.prices.to_a.sum(&:price_attribute), where price_attribute is the attribute that holds the price value in the price model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mgidea already correctly said:

You want to create a `has_many :through` relationship in your `Student` model first and then you want to convert the `prices` of your `Student` into an `Array` with `#to_a` and then create the `sum` of your `price_attribute`.

Add the following to your `Student` model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lessons
  has_many :prices, through: :lessons # <= Add this here
end
```

Your show action could than look like:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @student = Student.find(params[:id]

    @sum = @student.prices.to_a.sum(&:price)
    # Equivalent to:
    # @sum = @student.prices.to_a.sum { |p| return p.price }
  end
end
```

Than you could use the instance variable `@sum` in your view.

Hope this helps!

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Addin a query of sum in controller does it.
Answer: https://github.com/yshmarov/myclass101/commit/9a998da2af07caee76948d2941ad006029a0f47a